# dot product as a function of permutation of elements

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question

Given two sets of $n$ numbers $x_1<\ldots <x_n$ and $y_1<\ldots< y_n$, I had an exercise to show that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_{\pi(i)}$ is maximized over all permutations $\pi$ when $\pi$ is the identity, i.e., the elements of each sequence with the same rank are multiplied. Is there a general concept of "agreement" between two permutations $\pi,\pi'$, where the dot product $\sum_{i=1}^n x_{\pi'(i)}y_{\pi(i)} $ is larger when this measure of agreement is larger?

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) will help.

Comment: @Somos TIL. Thanks for this reference. The proof goes about as I expected.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, but I imagine such a measure would depend only on $\pi' \pi^{-1}$, so really it would be a measure of a single permutation. A possible definition of a partial order on permutations would then be to define $\pi \leq \pi'$ if $\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_{\pi(i)} \leq \sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_{\pi'(i)}$ irrespective of the values of the $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s. I think it's easy to prove antisymmetry.